# Extra text in the sidebar for 1 menu item and his sub-menu items?

Tags: php

In the main menu i have 3 channels "About, Service, Contact". The page "About" has 3 sub-pages, my issue is in the sidebar in channel "About" i need a text which is only on this page visible and his sub-pages. I tried with:

```
get_the_ID()
```

but this is not correct because i get everytime different id, which method have i to use to set it only for this channel?

Comment: Please post *all* of your code. It is impossible to tell what you are doing. Do you need the "text" in the menu? Somewhere else in the page? What?

Comment: This is the code in my sidebar.php: http://pastebin.com/qrtE7iDc, i have on all pages something trough widgets, but only for "About" page i need this code.

Comment: Post your code inline, but if the problem is a widget then the widget code is the important code, not the sidebar itself.